# If I got many to many relationship data first, how do I insert them to my table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, insert, entity-relationship

Say I have a customer table, a product table and an order table to record who buys what, the order table basically has 2 foreign keys, customer_id & product_id.

Now I got the order information first, within in it I can't find the customer information in my local database. As it turns out this is a new customer, whose information will come later from another thread/queue. To make things even worse the customer id I got from the order information is not the same one I used locally. My local customer id is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (I do record that "true customer id" as another column and set index on it)

So how I do record this order information? I can come up with some clumsy solution, e.g. if I can't find contact info, I insert a record for it first. Later after I get the real information for this customer, I update customer & order table. But I was wondering is there any "standard" way for the situation like this?

Answer (score 1):

Inserting NULL values, and then updating with the real values later, is simple and will work (if you don't have a NOT NULL constraint).
You should use a transaction so that concurrent users don't see the incomplete data.

You could use [deferred foreign key constraints](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_deferred):

> If a statement modifies the contents of the database such that a deferred foreign key constraint is violated, the violation is not reported immediately. Deferred foreign key constraints are not checked until the transaction tries to COMMIT. For as long as the user has an open transaction, the database is allowed to exist in a state that violates any number of deferred foreign key constraints.

However, deferred foreign key constraints are useful only if you are inserting values that violate the constraint; a NULL value is not considered a FK violation.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and that was the solution I came up with. I was wondering is there any other way to do it?

Comment: "deferred foreign key constraints" is helpful. Thanks!